# Why does Twitter Bootstrap require multiple classes for buttons?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

To make a primary button using [Twitter's Bootstrap library](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons), you need to use two CSS classes like so: `class="btn btn-primary"`.

Why did they design the API this way, when they could have made btn-primary include all of the CSS that btn includes? Is it purely to save on code duplication and therefore file size or is there a more complex reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because of [OOCSS](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/12/an-introduction-to-object-oriented-css-oocss/) principles. Detaching certain styles from elements allows for better code and style reuse and a easier way to rapidly modify any object in your css. For example, you have your main `.btn` class that styles your button with the default grey color, so all buttons with the `.btn` class will have the same style, but with predefined styles you can extend that same button class to support multiple different color schemes without the need to write the default `.btn` properties over and over again, so its easier to maintain. If you look at the css for the `.btn-warning` and all other button state classes you can see that they just define the color and style of the button and skip the need to rewrite the button class once again;

```
.btn-warning:hover, .btn-warning:active, .btn-warning.active, .btn-warning.disabled, .btn-warning[disabled] {
    background-color: #F89406;
}
```

This allows for easier to read and shorter,more cleaner stylesheets.

Comment: This is a fair point, but consider that Twitter is compiled with LESS and therefore can you can get all these DRY advantages as a developer and only the result is repetitive.

Comment: @Steve Compiled less should render the same benefits of OOCSS, its just a different way to write it so no repetition. The next version of the bootstrap components that is coming up is being built on this principle per [roadmap](http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2012/03/coming-up-in-bootstrap/)

Answer (score 6):

Because `btn-primary` isn't the default button. It's additional CSS that turns it blue much like `btn-success` turns it green.

The default button is grey.

Comment: Right. And Steve, it *is* about saving on code repetition; `.btn` has all the main structure of the button look and feel, but additional classes allow color-changing quite easily. I don't use Twitter Bootstrap, but on many projects of mine, both personal and at work, I've done the same method of having a generic button class and allowing other classes for coloring.