# Bootstrap - why do I need two classes to style a button?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is how you style a button in Bootstrap:

```html
<button class="btn btn-default">Do Something</button>
```

Two classes must be applied just to get a button. I see similar pattern in other parts of Bootstrap too:

```html
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok">
```

I would like to reduce the number of classes used within my HTML. One way how to do this is using *less* mixins:

```css
.btn-default {
    .btn;
    .btn-default;
}
.glyphicon-ok {
    .glyphicon;
    .glyphicon-ok;
}
```

Then my HTML can be simplified to this:

```html
<button class="btn-default">Do Something</button>
<i class="glyphicon-ok">
```

Is this a good idea? Am I losing something by combining the general class (`.btn`, `.glyphicon`) with the specific one (`.btn-default`, `.glyphicon-ok`)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question is similar to [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10501544/10251345) on this site, where [Andres Ilich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/680398/andres-ilich) has [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10501638/revisions):

> This is because of
> [OOCSS](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/12/an-introduction-to-object-oriented-css-oocss/)
> principles. Detaching certain styles from elements allows for better
> code and style reuse and a easier way to rapidly modify any object in
> your css. For example, you have your main `.btn` class that styles
> your button with the default grey color, so all buttons with the
> `.btn` class will have the same style, but with predefined styles you
> can extend that same button class to support multiple different color
> schemes without the need to write the default `.btn` properties over
> and over again, so its easier to maintain. If you look at the css for
> the `.btn-warning` and all other button state classes you can see that
> they just define the color and style of the button and skip the need
> to rewrite the button class once again;
>
> ```
> .btn-warning:hover, .btn-warning:active, .btn-warning.active, .btn-warning.disabled, .btn-warning[disabled] {
>     background-color: #F89406;
> }
> ```
>
> This allows for easier to read and shorter,more cleaner stylesheets.

Comment: -1 .. you copy/pasted this answer word for word (and received 10 upvotes, how unfair)

Comment: @user2129623 While I tend to agree what was done is unfair, it would be difficult to argue against sharing ([CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)) if the action is in accordance with the licensing terms (apparently, the author did make an honest attempt for attribution by stating the source; hence, I've edited it into better shape without escalation). If you are authorized to options like edit or flag an unfitting post, please try to ensure that our votes do not misinform readers about its content, but I appreciate that you have given an explanation in the comment.